# Discord API voice_message

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Всем привет. Хочу с помощью бота отправлять в текстовые каналы голосовые сообщения. Как я знаю, это можно делать только с телефона. Но я читал, что есть "обходные" пути, которые например используют различные сервисы по "улучшению" дискорда. Может кто-нибудь знает, как можно с бота отправить голосовое сообщение? Возможно залезть в код или что-то вроде этого.